# how get message of error by ajaxError?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My php code:

```
throw Exception("Lorem !", 403);
```

now I want by ajaxError, get `Lorem !` :

```
$(document).on('ajaxError', function(el, jqxhr) {
  console.log(xhr.statusText);
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
```

that `xhr.statusText` give me `Forbidden` message, not `Lorem !`.
and `xhr.responseText` give all html code of 403 Page !
How can give `Lorem !` text instead?

Comment: Depends on how your server handles exceptions, you are not giving details here.

Comment: Look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693423/clean-way-to-throw-php-exception-through-jquery-ajax-and-json)